# test unitario con metodo que hace new en un objeto

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Estoy haciendo test de una aplicacion. En una de las clases tengo este metodo, para comprobar que el rabbitmq esta operativo:

```
Protected function check(): void
{ 
    $parameters = $this->container->getParameter(‘rabbitmq.server’);
    $mq = new Connection($parameters);
    Try {
          $mq->connect();
          $mq->ping();
          $mq->disconnect();
          $this->service[‘mq’] = true;
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
          $this->service[‘mq’] = false;
    }
}
```

Para hacer la parte de try no he visto problema. Tengo este test:

```
public function testMQTry(): void
{
    $servers = [‘host’ =>’rabbitmq’, ‘user’=> ‘user’, ‘pass’=> ‘pass’];
    $container = $this->getMockBuilder(ContainerInterface::class);
    $container
        ->method('getParameter')
        ->willReturn($servers);
    $status = new MonitorMq();
    $status->setContainer($container);
    $result = $status->status();
    $this->assertEmpty($result);
}
```

Mi problema es que no puedo testear la parte de `catch`, debido a que el servidor siempre esta funcionando. Para comprobar esa parte tendria que hacer de alguna manera un mock del objeto Connection(asi podria configurar uno de los metodos para que lance una exception), pero el objeto Connection se crea directamente en el metodo.

No veo manera de hacer esto. Alguien sabe como?

Comment: Quizá [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7763207/5587982) te sirva. Mira también el concepto llamado [*Dobles de prueba*](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/es/latest/test-doubles.html), que probablemente aplicaría en tu caso. La traducción castellana no es muy dichosa :-), si sabes inglés léelo mejor [en inglés](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/test-doubles.html)...

Comment: lo de los dobles lo habia pensado, pero seguia con el mismo problema, ya que sigue el new dentro del metodo. He revisado el enlace voy a probar la idea de sacar el new a un metodo y luego hacer el stub. gracias!!!

Comment: En *Dobles de prueba* te dice esto: «*The `__construct()` and `__clone()` methods of the original class are not executed and the arguments passed to a method of the test double will not be cloned. If these defaults are not what you need then you can use the `getMockBuilder($type)` method to customize the test double generation using a fluent interface...*» No sé si es exactamente lo que necesitas...

Comment: al final, la solucion ha sido con parte de lo que has dicho, @A.Cedano. He hecho una funcion que hace el new, y luego un mock de mi clase con ese metodo mockeado. Con eso ya puedo controlar el devolver un Connection que me interesa. Pongo una solucion?

Comment: Sí, ponlo como respuesta por si alguien en un futuro tiene un problema parecido. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Al final, he aplicado parte de lo comentado por `@A. Cedano` y he llegado al siguiente resultado.

Lo primero, es extraer ese new que tenemos en el codigo, a un metodo getNewConnection(), que unicamente devuelve el objeto new. (He añadido la etiqueta **@codeCoverageIgnore** debido a que el metodo no tiene sentido luego testearlo). El codigo quedaria asi:

```
Protected function check(): void
{ 
    $parameters = $this->container->getParameter(‘rabbitmq.server’);
    $mq = $this->getNewConnection($parameters);
    Try {
          $mq->connect();
          $mq->ping();
          $mq->disconnect();
          $this->service[‘mq’] = true;
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
          $this->service[‘mq’] = false;
    }
}
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
Protected function getNewConnection($parameters) : Connection
{
    Return new Connection($parameters);
}
```

Ahora, con este metodo getNewConnection, podemos hacer un mock parcial (es un mock al que especificamos los metodos que queremos sobreescribir). Con esto ahora podemos cambiar el test de Try asi:

```
public function getMonitorPartialMock()
{
    return $this->getMockBuilder(Connection::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['getNewConnection'])
        ->getMock();
}

public function testMQTry(): void
{
    $servers = [‘host’ =>’rabbitmq’, ‘user’=> ‘user’, ‘pass’=> ‘pass’];
    $container = $this->getMockBuilder(ContainerInterface::class);
    $container
        ->method('getParameter')
        ->willReturn($servers);
    $status = $this->getMonitorPartialMock();
    $status->setContainer($container);
    $result = $status->status();
    $this->assertEmpty($result);
}
```

Como es un mock parcial, si no definimos nada se comporta como un metodo normal. Ahora podemos hacer el catch:

```
public function testMQTry(): void
{
    $servers = [‘host’ =>’rabbitmq’, ‘user’=> ‘user’, ‘pass’=> ‘pass’];
    $container = $this->getMockBuilder(ContainerInterface::class);
    $container
        ->method('getParameter')
        ->willReturn($servers);
    $status = $this->getMonitorPartialMock();
    $myConnection = $this->getMock(Connection::class)
        ->method(‘connect’)
       ->willThrowException(new \Exception());
    $status
        ->method(‘getNewConnection’)
        ->willReturn($myConnection);
    $status->setContainer($container);
    $result = $status->status();
    $this->assertEmpty($result);
}
```

Ahora en este metodo, podemos crear el objeto NewConnection como un mock, y lanzar una exception en el metodo "connect". De esta manera, salta el try y se ejecuta el catch (que es lo que queria conseguir).